# Determine whether the statement or its negation is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether the statement or its negation is true.

$\exists a,b\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $\forall c,d\in\Bbb{Z}^+, a/b = c/d$.
Negation: $\forall a,b\in\Bbb{Z}^+, \exists c,d\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $a/b\neq c/d$.

I am not sure how to prove this, can someone help pls.

Comment: Welcome. Please use MathJax to format your questions - I’ve done this for you here. You should show your thoughts so far

Comment: Suppose $c_1, d_1, c_2, d_2 = 1,2,1,3,~$ respectively.  Then, there has to exist an $a,b$ such that $(1/2) = (a/b) = (1/3).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proof of the negation:
given $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, if $a=b$ then $\frac{a}{b} \neq \frac{2}{1}$ and if $a\neq b$ then $\frac{a}{b}\neq \frac{1}{1}$

Comment: Still confused, can you explain more detail why negation is True? why a/b≠c/d?

Comment: To show that the negation is true, you need to find $c,d$ for any given $a,b$ such that $\frac{a}{b}\neq \frac{c}{d}$.

Given $a=b$, choosing $c=2,d=1$ always gives the desired inequality.

Given $a\neq b$, choosing $c=1,d=1$ always gives the desired inequality.
Thus the negation is true

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\exists a,b\in \Bbb Z^+\,\forall c,d\in \Bbb Z^+\,(a/b=c/d)\implies$

$\exists a,b\in \Bbb Z^+\,(a/b=1/1\land a/b=2/1)\implies$

$1=2$.